# QGIS crashes when printing

Tags: qgis, printing

I have a 50 MB shapefile. I am trying to import it into Illustrator. When I try printing to an svg file from the Print Composer, QGIS crashes. I am using QGIS Essen 2.14.3. I have tried lots of different things:

- simplifying the geometry (QGIS crashes)
- trying to print to a postscript file (will only print to a prn file, which Illustrator can't read)
- installing Cute PDF (doesn't really work in Illustrator)

I am using a laptop with Windows 10, 32 bit and 4gb of RAM.

Will upgrading to a new machine with 8gb of RAM and 64 bit windows 10 make any difference?

I can't afford a new laptop, but I need to output to Illustrator so will probably have to bite the bullet.

Comment: 50MB isn't that massive. An upgrade to 8GB will only help if RAM is the problem - if you run a memory usage monitor is the QGIS process filling up? Does this workflow work okay for small shapefiles? How are you trying to simplify the geometry when that crashes? Again, check the memory usage before you spend on a new machine.

Comment: Best is if you can share your data and project on hub.qgis.org so the developers can test what's happening

Comment: I use QGIS then export to svg then import to illustrator (for creating layered pdf)'s have done this with pdf files over 120mb without issue. [laptop is an i7 windows 10 with 12GB RAM)

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried it again today and it is still crashing. I checked the memory usage and it didn't go higher than about 70%. I read in another post on the web that it might have something to do with Windows 32 bit. Apparently, the 64-bit system works much better as does LInux. It is probably not worth upgrading my current machine to 64 bit windows so I  may as well buy a new one. In the interim, I will try some other things and report back.

Comment: I upgraded my laptop to an i7 windows 10 with 8GB RAM. Everything works  fine.